# Installed UBUNTU Server and wont recognize full HDD Capacity

Tags: linux, ssh, hard-disk

Hello i dont quite understand why when i installed the server i made sure to clean wipe the disk and use all the disk of 250gb to make 1 partition but only now there is only 97gb that i can use so i would like to know how could i possibly do that or if it is impossible :(

here is a picture so you could better understand

[image]

Comment: Add the output of `pvs`, `vgs`, and `lvs` to the question. Copy and past the text with codeblocks. Do not post pictures. What it looks like is that the volume group and logical volume only have 98GB of the space allocated to them of the 250GB that are available.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: Okay thank you & how could i reallocate the volume and logical group so they use the full 250gb availaible

Answer (score 0):

Do not post pictures.

Look at output of these two commands:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
$ mount | grep /dev/sda
```

They will show which sections of hard disk is used and for what.

You will either find a large gap between partitions in the output of `fdisk`, or find that some partition is not mounted.